# How to get text of URL from notepad plus?

Tags: regex, url, notepad++

I have this text:

```
1135/how-are-you-86789/pp
1125/example-fran%C3%A7aise-86749/pp
1125/episode-6-movie-86749/pp
```

Can you give me the regex which can get text "something", please ?. So, the ouput will be:

```
how-are-you
example-fran%C3%A7aise
episode-6-movie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How  about something like

```
/[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+/g
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kN5pX8/1)

**EDIT 1**

To replace the contents, a small change in regex would help

```
^(?:[^\/]+\/)?([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+).*$/gm
```

Replaced with `\1`, capture group content

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kN5pX8/2)

---

**EDIT 2**

```
^[^\/]+\/([^-\/\n]+(?:-[^-\/\n]+(?=-))+).*$
```

replace with `\1`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bY3nE9/1)

Comment: Yes, right. So, how to extract them ? What I type in "replace with" ? Thank you very much !

Comment: @Ban I have edited my answer. See the demo on how it works. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hi, if "something" is number or special character (%,...), it will not work. So, do you any way to do that ?

Comment: @Ban It unclear because you havnt included the digits in the last two examples. So what makes `something` different from `86789` or `86749`

Comment: Hi, I added more 2 url. Sorry for my unclear. If you can fix it, it is so great !

Comment: @Ban Can digits apear in `something`?

Comment: Hello, Yes, digits can appear in something

Comment: @Ban But i am little confused because if digits can apear in `something` then why is `-86789` not included in something. If you can clear me there i may be able to solve :)